# Add Left Padding to Y Axis in GraphView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-graphview

The decimals on my Y axis are being covered by white spaces.

Reference below.

[image: graph]

Here is my GraphView XML code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:elevation="30dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/activity_full_screen_humid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorGrey"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_text2"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:text="@string/overall_humid"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/fullscreen2"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:onClick="onFullScreen"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/fullscreen_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

These are the functions I used.

```
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(this));
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(2);

        graph.getViewport().setMinX(d1.getTime());
        graph.getViewport().setMaxX(d3.getTime());
        graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
```

Increasing the layout_margin does not change anything. It just makes the whole graph smaller instead.

Is there a way to add some left padding so that I can see the whole decimal on my Y axis?

Comment: can you please try by removing margin?

Comment: also can you please show me your layout structure?

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur hi sir, still the same.

Comment: can you please attach your layout structure to understand it?

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur i have edited the post to include my layout structure.

Comment: can you please remove margin and elevation from the cardview and test it working or not?

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur nope. still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around with the functions, I've found a solution. Apparently you can set the label padding by using getGridLabelRenderer.setPadding().

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setPadding(40);
```